# How to dynamically change line-height or font size of a link(<a>)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is what my project looks like:

[image]

Each red box is a link. Right now I have them as  tags with a line-height matching the height of the box, so that the text is vertically centered. The problem i am running into is when the text that needs to go on a tile is too long. How would i be able to make the text wrap if it is too long? Is there a way to find if the string will fit within a certain width?

Would changing the way i have the tiles set up make this easier? I thought about just making the Divs clickable, but then im still not sure how to make the text vertically aligned in the center. I just need a pointing in the right direction. Thanks

EDIT: some of the code

the html of a tile:

```
<div class="primary col_1 row_1">
    <a href="javascript:expand(1, 1)">
        <?php echo $tile_data[0][0]; ?>
    </a>
</div>
```

The CSS applicable:

```
#selection_menu a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 162px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
    border: none;
    float: left;
}
#selection_menu .primary_options .primary a { font-size: 23px; height: 108px; }
```

Comment: `max-width:250px; wrap-word:break-word;`? You could show us some of the markup you have atm and an example of what you'd have problems with.

Comment: If you don't want the text to wrap, you might want to have a look at this plugin if it fits your needs. It will automatically change the font size to fit the desired width: http://www.frequency-decoder.com/demo/slabText/

Comment: @3rror404 would i do that by just finding how many pixels of padding i need on the top and bottom to center it?

Comment: If you want your box to be 30px high and your font size is 10px you would add 10px padding top and bottom

Comment: Right, didn't realize you could measure font in px.. but anyways wouldn't this still cause the same problem of the string was too long?

Comment: Also - the padding method changes the area of the tile that can be clicked, which i don't want.

Comment: I think I miss understood your question. Are you wanting the "tiles" to remain the same height even if the text runs on to two lines? If so, I don't think is possible with CSS. JavaScript is probably the way to go

Comment: Yeah i am looking for the tiles to stay the same size.. If i could figure out how many lines the text needs i could do it with javascript, but do you have any thoughts on how to do that?

Comment: I think i am oging to have to change and do everything with buttons instead

Comment: Actually you could probably do it with CSS. Look at "display:table". Typing on my phone so can't really write an example

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following (add proper colors and typography):

```
#selection_menu div a {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 108px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 162px
}
```

This will vertically center every `a` inside a `div` (inside `#selection_menu`), no matter how many lines it spans. Works in all modern Web browsers. You can set `line-height` to a proper value like `1.5` (it will define the way the link looks when it spans across multiple lines).

Comment: This doesn't seem to be doing anything on my end.. i think the issue is that the height of the link is the same height of the div it is in...

Comment: You mean this doesn’t vertically align the text for you? Perhaps something else is conflicting then. See this Fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/eUV4X/1/).

Comment: there must be something else, i just changed them all to buttons instead and got it all working. Thank you though!